# Images and Audios in SFMC Mobile push notifications

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

Is it possible to send images and audios in mobile push notifications in SFMC? I have seen an insert option while creating a message where we can add any personalization field. But how do we add an option of images in that list?

Answer (score 1):

great question. I'm the product owner for the SDKs. Supporting images in push is something we're very busy working on for iOS and Android. Though we do have some lightweight image support in Android today, we're working on first class support of images on both platforms. Please stay tuned.

[Current Android Image Support](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/features/picture-notifications.html)

Comment: Thanks for the update Andrew! Looking forward to getting more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the support for this depends on each OS vendor like ios or android.

Looks like Sfdc will support anything supported to vendor.

That class [PushNotificationPayload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_Messaging_PushNotificationPayload_methods.htm) has a method for apple device to specify alter sound file.

Comment: This isn't a SFDC question.